How to use Graph QL queries to get authenticated user in Next JS middleware?
I am running my NextJs 14 app with Apollo Client and A Apollo Server graphql backend on two different servers, i.e: separated. i have used "graphql-passport" to save sessions and authenticated user in my backend.
When i login, a cookie is set with the help of passport called "connect.sid" and a session entry is created in the mongo db.
I have a GraphQl query "authUser" which i can use from the frontend to fetch the Authenticated user.
When i use this query inside a component (.tsx file wrapped inside Apollo Provider) it works fine.
But if I want to the query to work inside NextJs middleware.ts so that I can handle protected routes and other logic, i can't get it to working.
I specifically want to use the query as i dont want to just check with the cookie, i want the token to be verified from the backend.
I tried different methods like using Server actions and using just the "client.query" and other methods but to no avail. Below are the files:
User.resolver.js (server)
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

import User from "../models/User.Schema.js";

const userResolver = {
  Mutation: {
    signUp: async (_, { input }, context) => {
      try {
        const { email, password, name } = input;

        if (!email || !password || !name) {
          throw new Error("All fields are required");
        }

        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (existingUser) {
          throw new Error("User already exists");
        }

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        // Keep retrying until a unique uniqueId is generated
        let newUser;

        newUser = new User({
          email,
          password: hashedPassword,
          name,
        });
        await newUser.save();
        await context.login(newUser);

        return newUser;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in signup: ", error);
        throw new Error(error.message || "Internal Server Error");
      }
    },
    signUpAdmin: async (_, { input }, context) => {
      try {
        const { email, password, name, orgaizationName } = input;
      } catch (error) {}
    },
    login: async (_, { input }, context) => {
      try {
        const { email, password } = input;

        if (!email || !password) {
          throw new Error("All fields are required");
        }

        const { user } = await context.authenticate("graphql-local", {
          email,
          password,
        });

        await context.login(user);

        return user;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in login: ", error);
        // If the error is related to authentication failure, return a specific error message
        if (error.name === "AuthenticationError") {
          throw new Error("Incorrect username or password");
        } else {
          // If the error is not related to authentication failure, return a generic error message
          throw new Error(error.message || "Internal server error");
        }
      }
    },
  },
  Query: {
    authUser: async (_, __, context) => {
      try {
        console.log("CONTEXT: ", context);
        const user = await context.req.user;
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in authUser: ", error);
        throw new Error(error.message || "Internal Server Error");
      }
    },
  },
};

export default userResolver;

index.ts (server)
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import cors from "cors";
import path, { resolve } from "path";

import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { expressMiddleware } from "@apollo/server/express4";
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from "@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import passport from "passport";
import { buildContext } from "graphql-passport";
import session from "express-session";
import connectMongo from "connect-mongodb-session";

import { configurePassport } from "./passport/passport.config.js";
import { connectDb } from "./utils/connectDb.js";
import mergedTypeDefs from "./typeDefs/index.js";
import mergedResolvers from "./resolvers/index.js";

dotenv.config();
configurePassport();

const __dirname = path.resolve();
const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

const MongoDBStore = connectMongo(session);
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  collection: "sessions",
});

store.on("error", (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
      httpOnly: true,
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: mergedTypeDefs,
  resolvers: mergedResolvers,
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
});

await server.start();

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }),
  // {
  //   origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  //   credentials: true,
  // }
  express.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server, {
    context: async ({ req, res }) => buildContext({ req, res }),
  })
);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));

// app.get("*", (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"));
// });

await new Promise((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port: 8080 }, resolve));
await connectDb();

console.log(`Server ready at: http://localhost:8080/graphql`);


auth.ts for my Next JS app
// auth.js

import { client } from "@/components/apolloProvider/provider";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export async function isUserAuthenticated(req) {
  try {
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: gql`
        query GetAuthenticatedUser {
          authUser {
            uniqueId
          }
        }
      `,
    });

    console.log("data: ", data);

    // If the authenticated user exists, return true
    return !!data.authenticatedUser;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error checking authentication:", error);
    return false; // Return false if there's an error
  }
}


middleware.ts NextJs
import { isUserAuthenticated } from "./auth";
import {
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  apiAuthPrefix,
  authRoutes,
  publicRoutes,
} from "@/routes";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "./components/apolloProvider/provider";

export async function middleware(req) {
  const { nextUrl } = req;

  const isLoggedIn = await isUserAuthenticated(req);

  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isAuthRoute) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
    }
    return null;
  }

  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL("/sign-in", nextUrl));
  }

  return null;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Exclude files with a "." followed by an extension, which are typically static files.
    // Exclude files in the _next directory, which are Next.js internals.
    "/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)",
    "/",
    // Re-include any files in the api or trpc folders that might have an extension
    "/(api|trpc)(.*)",
  ],
};


I don't want to use Prisma DB as many tutorials show, neither do i want to use server actions. I want to keep my frontend and backend logic at different places.
I have tried Server actions, client.query, as well as UseQuery. None works. Any type of solution using these technologies is encouraged.
